# In Swift: how could I sort the smallest number to the highest?

Tags: swift, dictionary, select

Here is my data:

```
["aRetinol": (800.0, 24.0, 3.0, 24.0, 3.0), "aBetacarotene": (2100.0, 231.0, 11.0, 100.0, 4.7619047), "vitamineC": (80.0, 197.38002, 246.72504, 100.0, 125.0), "vitamineB1": (1.1, 0.6, 54.545456, 0.6, 54.545456), "omega3": (2.0, 2.06, 103.0, 2.06, 103.0), "calcium": (800.0, 297.4, 37.175, 100.0, 12.5)]
```

It's a dictionary type : `[String: (Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)]`

This is for a table view where I have to display the second smallest value of each nutrient.

I need to obtain a dictionary like this (the value concerned is between **) :

```
["calcium": (800.0, **297.4**, 37.175, 100.0, 12.5), "aBetacarotene": (2100.0, **231.0**, 11.0, 100.0, 4.7619047),"vitamineC": (80.0, **197.38002**, 246.72504, 100.0, 125.0), "aRetinol": (800.0, **24.0**, 3.0, 24.0, 3.0), "omega3": (2.0, **2.06**, 103.0, 2.06, 103.0), "vitamineB1": (1.1, **0.6**, 54.545456, 0.6, 54.545456)]
```

Comment: First of all, have you tried to solve this yourself and if so please share your code and secondly, I would recommend using a struct instead of that tuple and thirdly, dictionaries are unordered and can't be sorted. I just realised I wrote this in the wrong order :)

Comment: i am already working on a struct for it

Comment: Maybe you should start with that then because then you can move from a dictionary to an array of your custom type and arrays can be sorted.

Comment: "I have to display the second smallest value of each nutrient"  
You highlighted the second larges values in your sample data.

Comment: janusfidel: i mean the second numbers of the different tuples, has to be th criterion to sort this dictionnary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, a struct might work better than a tuple for this kind of data.

Also, you can't sort a dictionary and get a dictionary as a result because the dictionary is not an ordered collection, i.e. you can't have the keys be ordered arbitrarily. A result of sorting a dictionary will be an array of tuples where each tuple consists of a key and a value.

That said, if you had no choice but using tuples, here's how this problem could be solved:

```swift
extension Dictionary where Value == (Float, Float, Float, Float, Float) {
    func sortedBySecondSubvalue(ascending: Bool) -> [(key: Key, value: Value)] {
        self.sorted { keyValuePair1, keyValuePair2 -> Bool in
            let secondSubvalue1 = keyValuePair1.value.1
            let secondSubvalue2 = keyValuePair2.value.1
            return ascending ? secondSubvalue1 < secondSubvalue2 : secondSubvalue1 > secondSubvalue2
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```swift
let sampleDict: [String:(Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)] = ["aRetinol": (800.0, 24.0, 3.0, 24.0, 3.0), "aBetacarotene": (2100.0, 231.0, 11.0, 100.0, 4.7619047), "vitamineC": (80.0, 197.38002, 246.72504, 100.0, 125.0), "vitamineB1": (1.1, 0.6, 54.545456, 0.6, 54.545456), "omega3": (2.0, 2.06, 103.0, 2.06, 103.0), "calcium": (800.0, 297.4, 37.175, 100.0, 12.5)]

print(sampleDict.sortedBySecondSubvalue(ascending: false))
// Prints: [(key: "calcium", value: (800.0, 297.4, 37.175, 100.0, 12.5)), (key: "aBetacarotene", value: (2100.0, 231.0, 11.0, 100.0, 4.7619047)), (key: "vitamineC", value: (80.0, 197.38002, 246.72504, 100.0, 125.0)), (key: "aRetinol", value: (800.0, 24.0, 3.0, 24.0, 3.0)), (key: "omega3", value: (2.0, 2.06, 103.0, 2.06, 103.0)), (key: "vitamineB1", value: (1.1, 0.6, 54.545456, 0.6, 54.545456))]
```

The extension like that can be surely modified for dictionaries containing structs as values rather than tuples.

Comment: If you would like to make your sort generic and also allow to increase or decrease sort `func sortedBySecondSubvalue<T: Comparable>(by areInIncreasingOrder: ((T,T)-> Bool) = (<)) -> [Element] where Value == (T, T, T, T, T) { sorted { areInIncreasingOrder($0.value.1, $1.value.1) } }`